# How to get a specific foreign key value

Tags: python, django

My models.py look like that:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

In my function I have access to the Order table and I am trying to get information about the quantity of Item.

I tried that: `order.items.item.quantity`, but I get that error: `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'item'`

How would I get the quantity number from Item table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the related queryset as,

```
order = Order.objects.get(id=123)
for order_item in order.items.all():
    print(order_item.item.quantity)
```

or use **`values()`** method as,

```
order = Order.objects.get(id=123)
result = order.items.values('item__quantity')
```

Comment: Ok second option `values` is giving me this value `<QuerySet [{'item__quantity': 2}]>` , can I make so it just returns the number?

Comment: What else are you expecting?

Comment: Do you know how would I update the table using the first option? I got `order_item.item.quantity += 1`, when I use order.save(), it doesn't update